# SharePoint Rest API Patch request to update list item not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, updatelistitems, jquery-ajax

I have an application build up in SharePoint 2013. In one of the custom list form, we are trying to update list item using Rest API call with type **Patch**.

Few users are getting a response ***{"readyState":4,"responseText":"404 NOT FOUND","status":404,"statusText":"NOT FOUND"}*** , while others are able to update the item successfully.

Code :

```
function CloseCaseRecord(itemID) {
var item = {
    __metadata: {
        type: "SP.Data.CaseRecordListItem"
    },
    CaseStatus: "Closed"
}
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CaseRecord')/items(" + itemID + ")",
    type: "PATCH",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        alert('Case closed successfully');
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(data.responseJSON.error);
    }
});
}
```

Note: Same code works fine for the users if the request is changed from type **Patch to Post**. The issue is inconsistent with users, with Patch method

Answer (score 0):

Patch request was getting blocked on server and this issue came up since Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 (x64) was installed on the server for some other application by the server admin team.

Due to the URL Rewrite module, few of the Patch requests were getting blocked and returned **404 error**

Post Uninstall of this module from the server issue has been resolved.

Microsoft URL Rewrite Module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite